# Drupal 7 - remove divs

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to show the result as below:

```
<div class="mainmenu">
<h2 class="sidebar1">Main Menu</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is a dummy link 10</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

However, I see that in D7, some extra divs are added with the result and the UL class is not appeared. Please check the below result that D7 rendered:

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="view view-test1 view-id-test1 view-display-id-block view-dom-id-2e7dd9ae3682d3d6e095a22755b506c0">
            <div class="view-header">
         <div class="mainmenu">
   <h2 class="sidebar1">My Pages</h2>    </div>
           <ul>
        
              <li>page 1</li>            
              <li>page 2</li>            
              <li>page 3</li>      
    </ul>
    
    <div class="view-footer">
        </div>
 </div> 
</div>  
</div>
```

Can you please help me to remove the additional divs added by drupal as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off some of the extra markup within the Views settings, but you have to modify the templates used to render the view if that is not sufficient.

Comment: How can I modify the templates? Can you provide me some examples so that I can get an idea.